# Tags: Messaging-menu and memenu

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tags

Should we make [memenu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/memenu) a synonym on [messaging-menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/messaging-menu)

In looking at the questions in [memenu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/memenu) <del>it seems to be a abbreviation of "messaging"</del>.
Based on research by Eliah Kagan, the name is "Me Menu" and not a abbreviation,

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MeMenu:

> This specification is for the “me menu” that appeared in Ubuntu 10.04,
>   10.10, and 11.04.
>
> Warning /!\ This specification is now superseded by the system menu.

So should it be renamed to [system-menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-menu) because of the specification change? Or we could leave it alone since it is out of date.

---

There even seems to be confusion within answers as [one user](https://askubuntu.com/a/25711/47291) says:

> MeMenu(if you mean the "place" where you can change your status).

Comment: I don't know whether or not these tags should be synonymized, but it may be relevant that the "me" in "Me Menu" does *not* stand for "messaging." [It is not an abbreviation at all.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MeMenu)

Comment: @EliahKagan interesting, so are most people mislabeling this, or is there a separate menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the tag is fine.  We should retag questions where it is misused (e.g. [Empathy not showing in messageing menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206681/empathy-not-showing-in-memenu) and [Can I rearrange the messaging menu list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243799/can-i-rearrange-the-messaging-menu-list)) but since it [used to be part of the general UI](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/07/ubuntu-11-10-menu-goodbye) I think the tag has significance.

I could be wrong.  Maybe we are supposed to kill old obsolete tags.

Comment: I agree, there are questions using it right. I commented on a few of the general questions the referenced 12.04 and 12.10, to see which menu they are talking about.